# How to log/trace/print messages from within the contract ON-chain code, while using cardano-cli?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli, smart-contract

I'm wondering how to log/print/trace any message during the execution of a contract when submitted to the blockchain via `cardano-cli`.
So basically I hoped this very simple test script would show me something:

```
mkValidator :: ContractInfo -> () -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator _ _ _ _ = (traceIfFalse "Test" False) || True
```

However, when submitting a transaction with this script to `cardano-cli`, it gets executed without printing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your validator is basically `False || True`, which will always return `True`. The value from `traceIfFalse` is only passed to the user if the final result of the validator is False.

So if you are using the most recent version of cardano-cli the error should appear once you try to build a transaction removing the `|| True` part. If you want, however, to log an error even when the validation succeeds, this is impossible with Plutus, at least on-chain.